# small white pests moving on my soil need identification

Tags: identification, pests, pesticide

I see these very small white pests moving on the soil which belongs to my peace lily for around two weeks.

-they are just on the soil
-I haven't seen any change in their size or their color within these two weeks but they seem to grow in number slowly
-they are so small and I can't take pictures of em but this [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1em5dtf3rbxpm76/IMG_3507.mkv?dl=1):
help me identify and get rid of them please.

Comment: you can make a watering wick out of cotton or nylon to water the plant from a reservoir  below.  Keeps the roots moist and top dry.

Comment: good idea, have to do more research though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have soil mites. These are probably not harmful to your plants, but if the populations continues to grow then I'm sure you'd like to get them under control.

One simple thing you can do is avoid over-watering. Let the soil get dry before watering.

See [this article](https://sumogardener.com/tiny-white-bugs-in-soil/) for more information and ideas.

Comment: All right thanks, they look like soil mites.

Comment: Bad thing is I can't let the soil dry because there is a Peace Lily in it. I have to water it twice a week (its summer here) otherwise it droop it leaves. I think the potting mix contains about 30% of organic materials. I don't like seeing them in the soil so I'm going to try things suggested in that article you mentioned.   also, as a last resort, if they made me to completely re pot the plant in a new soil, can I sterilize the old soil by heating/baking it or there is no way other than disposing it?